# fill values based on value for matched IDs

Tags: r, data.table

I am looking for a `data.table` solution to a simply problem. I have data like so

```
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(
  id = seq(1:20),
  match_id = c( rep(1,5), rep(2,5), rep(3,5), rep(4,5)  ),
  exp = c( 1, rep(0,4), 1 , rep(0,4), 1 , rep(0,4), 1 , rep(0,4) )
)
data[, var := ifelse(exp==1, runif(1,min=0,max=100), 0), by = id]
```

I want, for each unique match_id where exp==0 to fill `var` based on the value of `var` for exp==1. Data to end up with:

```
data_want <- data.table(
  id = seq(1:20),
  match_id = c( rep(1,5), rep(2,5), rep(3,5), rep(4,5)  ),
  exp = c( 1, rep(0,4), 1 , rep(0,4), 1 , rep(0,4), 1 , rep(0,4) ),
  var = c(rep(data[1]$var,5), rep(data[6]$var,5), rep(data[11]$var,5), rep(data[16]$var,5))
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data[, var:=var[which(exp==1)], by=match_id]

       id match_id   exp       var
    <int>    <num> <num>     <num>
 1:     1        1     1 75.342705
 2:     2        1     0 75.342705
 3:     3        1     0 75.342705
 4:     4        1     0 75.342705
 5:     5        1     0 75.342705
 6:     6        2     1 81.822968
 7:     7        2     0 81.822968
 8:     8        2     0 81.822968
 9:     9        2     0 81.822968
10:    10        2     0 81.822968
11:    11        3     1  3.309884
12:    12        3     0  3.309884
13:    13        3     0  3.309884
14:    14        3     0  3.309884
15:    15        3     0  3.309884
16:    16        4     1  2.047301
17:    17        4     0  2.047301
18:    18        4     0  2.047301
19:    19        4     0  2.047301
20:    20        4     0  2.047301
       id match_id   exp       var
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert 0 to `NA` with `na_if` (from `dplyr`) and then use `nafill`

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
data[, var := nafill(na_if(var, 0), type = "locf")]
```

-output

```
> data
       id match_id   exp      var
    <int>    <num> <num>    <num>
 1:     1        1     1 42.81752
 2:     2        1     0 42.81752
 3:     3        1     0 42.81752
 4:     4        1     0 42.81752
 5:     5        1     0 42.81752
 6:     6        2     1 28.05760
 7:     7        2     0 28.05760
 8:     8        2     0 28.05760
 9:     9        2     0 28.05760
10:    10        2     0 28.05760
11:    11        3     1 76.53963
12:    12        3     0 76.53963
13:    13        3     0 76.53963
14:    14        3     0 76.53963
15:    15        3     0 76.53963
16:    16        4     1 50.95047
17:    17        4     0 50.95047
18:    18        4     0 50.95047
19:    19        4     0 50.95047
20:    20        4     0 50.95047
       id match_id   exp      var
```

---

Or another option is

```
data[, var := var[var!=0][cumsum(exp)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(
  id = seq(1:20),
  match_id = c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5), rep(3, 5), rep(4, 5)),
  exp = c(1, rep(0, 4), 1 , rep(0, 4), 1 , rep(0, 4), 1 , rep(0, 4))
)
data[, var := ifelse(exp==1, runif(1,min=0,max=100), 0), by = id]

data[, var := max(var), by = list(match_id)][]
#>     id match_id exp       var
#>  1:  1        1   1 40.474630
#>  2:  2        1   0 40.474630
#>  3:  3        1   0 40.474630
#>  4:  4        1   0 40.474630
#>  5:  5        1   0 40.474630
#>  6:  6        2   1 91.434384
#>  7:  7        2   0 91.434384
#>  8:  8        2   0 91.434384
#>  9:  9        2   0 91.434384
#> 10: 10        2   0 91.434384
#> 11: 11        3   1 61.503224
#> 12: 12        3   0 61.503224
#> 13: 13        3   0 61.503224
#> 14: 14        3   0 61.503224
#> 15: 15        3   0 61.503224
#> 16: 16        4   1  8.480375
#> 17: 17        4   0  8.480375
#> 18: 18        4   0  8.480375
#> 19: 19        4   0  8.480375
#> 20: 20        4   0  8.480375
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>